# no hit on if-statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, if-statement

I am trying to get a hit on my if-statement. I fetch qDiff (integer32) from the Core Data db and everything works except get a hit on the if-statements:

```
NSString *diff;

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [qContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"idQ: %@", [info valueForKey:@"idQ"]);
    NSLog(@"qDiff: %@", [info valueForKey:@"qDiff"]); //<<<<<<<<<Print correct number

    diff = [info valueForKey:@"qDiff"];
    NSLog(@"diff: %@", diff);       //<<<<<<<<<Print correct number

    if ([diff isEqual:@"1"]) NSLog(@"EASY");

    //if ([diff isEqualToString: @"2"]) NSLog(@"MEDIUM");
    //if ([[info valueForKey:@"qDiff"] isEqualToString: @"3"]) NSLog(@"HARD"); //<<<<<<tried this first


    NSLog(@"question: %@", [info valueForKey:@"question"]);
}        
[fetchRequest release];
```

I have been trying different If-statements but it does not trigger (print the NSLog).

Anyone that can give me a hint?

**=========UPDATE==========**

I changed to:

```
if ([diff isEqualToString:@"1"]) NSLog(@"EASY");
```

And got the following:

> 2010-12-12 15:39:49.321 XX_v2[2950:207] idQ: 0
>   2010-12-12 15:39:49.321 XX_v2[2950:207] qDiff: 1
>   2010-12-12 15:39:49.322 XX_v2[2950:207] diff: 1
>   2010-12-12 15:39:49.322 XX_v2[2950:207] -[_PFCachedNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0f9008
>   2010-12-12 15:39:49.324 XX_v2[2950:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_PFCachedNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0f9008'

**==========UPDATE #2=======**

Did try:

```
if ([diff isEqual:@"1"]) NSLog(@"EASY");
```

no difference in output:

> 2010-12-12 15:55:57.381 XX_v2[3151:207] idQ: 0
>   2010-12-12 15:55:57.382 XX_v2[3151:207] qDiff: 1
>   2010-12-12 15:55:57.382 XX_v2[3151:207] diff: 1
>   2010-12-12 15:55:57.382 XX_v2[3151:207] question: Do you want a new?

However, in the debugger i found:

> 'diff' "Variable not a CFString"

**========UPDATE#3========**

Updated the code above to show definition of 'diff'.

**========UPDATE#4========**

I did finally solve the problem with this statement:

```
if ([[info valueForKey:@"qDiff"] intValue] == 1) NSLog(@"EASY");
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `diff`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating `qDiff` as an NSString while Core Data saves it as an integer32 and exposes it as an NSNumber. Try this:

```
if ([diff isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) NSLog(@"EASY");
```

Or this:

```
if ([diff intValue] == 1) NSLog(@"EASY");
```

Answer (score 2):

You said  `qDiff` is  `integer32` in the data model. Then, the class is `NSNumber` in the Objective-C code, not `NSString`.

You should understand that in Objective-C, string objects, number objects, and non-object numbers are **not converted automatically**. And `==` doesn't work magically for all of the types and the classes.

So, you need to 
- use the appropriate classes explicitly, and then 
- convert them explicitly,
- and compare them with appropriate ways.

So, use

```
NSNumber* diff = [info valueForKey:@"qDiff"];
```

and perform either

```
if([diff isEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3]]){ ... }
```

or

```
if([diff intValue] == 3){ ... }
```