# Simple Numbers to string issue Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

So, this might be a little bit messy for me to explain, but here it goes.

I have, what i think are, numbers stored in core data and i am trying to convert them into strings so that i can use them as labels for table cells, maybe dumb but please bear with me.

I pump the core data items into an array and am trying to get them back out, i run a FOR loop and use this code to make a number for each item.

```
NSNumber *num = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
```

When i run, i get no errors and if i log them i get everything returned as expected. However, if i run this afterwards program force quits.

```
NSString *myOutput = [num stringValue];
```

I believe it is because what ever i actually have and am pulling out is not really a number therefore it cannot be made into a string using stringValue, anyone know a way to test for what an object is? Maybe using NSLog some how?

Also side question. In a FOR loop where i create objects I need to remember to release them each time the loop is run correct?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you post the code of the loop? There might be a memory issue.

Comment: First of all, a crash log would help. Where is your second line of code w.r.t to the first? And you don't need to release `num` as it is not retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways of checking what objects contain or whether they are of a certain type; either the

```
[myObject class];
```

check - if you break on a line after it you can see the class. With your NSNumber though, it will either be a number or have nothing inside it, ie

```
if (myNSNumber != nil)
    // then it must hold a value
```

Finally, there is this test - also perfectly viable:

```
if ([myProbableStringObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    // then let's do something with it
```

Also yes - you should release objects created in your for loop for best memory management and code efficiency. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Awesome!  Ok now it tells me that my so called number is a _PFCachedNumber, but if i create a different NSNumber with a more solid value, numberWithInt:10, it tells me it is a NSCFNumber, is there a way to turn a cached number into a NSCFNumber?

Comment: Sounds like a problem... page file cached number at a guess. After a quick lookup, sounds like the number is not being copied or set properly - the guy on this link reported the same error, may be worth a glance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422105/no-hit-on-if-statement Also, can you show/tell us where you create the original array that you want to copy and where your copy code is placed?

Comment: Ok so after some investigation, i have found out the following, my numbers entered into Core data are given as true NSNumbers, but when i retrieve them they are given back as _PFCachedNumbers, i cant imagine this is standard with how little on google there is for it. I made a new question here if you feel like taking a look.

Comment: Will do :) Glad to know of your outcome. Feel free to accept one of the answers if you can too - points for all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284470/coredata-number-returns-a-number-of-pfcachednumber-class

Answer (score 1):

You might try using:

```
NSLog( @"It is a '%@'", [[arr objectAtIndex:i] class] );
```

I think it should tell you what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that comes out an attribute of a managedObject is an object. There are no scalar values. Any numerical data is wrapped in a NSNumber instance.

I think the cause of your crash is more prosaic. If you put this variable assignment:

```
NSNumber *num = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
```

... inside the for-loop then `num` will be scoped only to the inside of the loop. Once the loop complete `num` will disappear.

Your crash is most likely caused by trying to access `num` after the loop completes. Simple move the declaration of num outside the loop like so:

NSNumber *num;
for (something;something++;something

... then this line:

```
NSString *myOutput = [num stringValue];
```

... will set `myOutput` to the value of `num` in the last iteration.