# Coredata number returns a number of PFCachedNumber class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

Like the title says i have a one to many relationship and the many accepts numbers, and it is given an NSNumber, however when i retrieve that number back from coredata it comes in the form of a PFCachedNumber. Any thoughts on why this may be?

Thanks!

```
for (UserNumber *info in pinNumberArray) {

//The numbers I'm after are inside ergTimes.
        NSSet *time = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:info.Times];

        for (ErgTimes *ergTimes in time){
            NSLog(@"Times Class : %@", [ergTimes.Twok class]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you retrieve data back out, do you assign the values returned and dump them into a fresh NSNumber? Also sounds like PFCachedNumber is an internal class that's part of Core Data in some manner - some very light info on the page linked below, that you may have already read. http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/

Comment: Hmm, ya even if i assign my coredata object to an NSNumber right as i pull it out it still tells me that it is an PFCashedNumber

Comment: Once you extract the data again, what was your task with it? Can you use it/output it etc without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. This is a common occurrence.

NSNumber, like most common API classes, is actually a "class cluster" in which a large number of classes masquerade as a single class. For example, if you initialize an NSString as a file path, you actually get back a class dedicated to handling file paths.

I haven't seen this particular class but I presume that `PF` stands for "PrivateFramework" just like `NS` stands for "NextStep" and `CF` stands for "CoreFoundation". It's likely an internal class we're not supposed to see easily.

(I am amused that they spelled "cached" incorrectly.)

You test for a class cluster with a class test like so:

```
[pfCashedNumerObject class] == NSNumber
```

Class-clusters internal classes all identify as the same public class.